# Obj C - Accessing custom class properties from and array of class objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I have a custom object class with some properties lets say.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *Name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *ImgURL;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray  *Messages;
```

I then go through a loop and populate the data and add each instance to an array like this

```
for(NSDictionary *eachEntry in details)
{
    ClientData *client;
    client.Name = [eachEntry objectForKey:@"name" ];
    client.ImgURL = [eachEntry objectForKey:@"img"];
    client.Messages = [eachEntry objectForKey:@"message" ];

    [_Data addObject:client];  
}
```

now in a table i want to display some of this data in a list, how can i get access to each property by name not key or index.

so at the moment i have this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 NSString *name = [[self.Data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"name"];
```

obviously this doesn't work because i haven't set keys

and i don't want to do this

```
NSString *name = [[self.Data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectAtIndex:1];
```

How can i access Client.Name etc

Comment: instance names beggining with small letter. For example: NSString *name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.Data is an array of ClientData objects so you can just do:

```
NSString *Name = ((ClientData *)[self.Data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).Name;
```

or:

```
ClientData *clientData = self.Data[indexPath.row];
NSString *name = clientData.Name;
```

Comment: Or: `NSString *name = [self.data[indexPath.row] Name];`.

Comment: BTW - the cast is not needed in the 2nd code example.

Answer (score 1):

[Key Value Coding (KVC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html). Replace `objectForKey` with `valueForKey`.

Comment: Hi Wain, does this give the same as JDx's answer, is there any reason to do it like this rather than JDx's

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to the question being asked.

Comment: KVC is a different and generic way of accessing a value from an object for a specified key. All of the options presented are runtime checks with different ways of making the compiler happy with the request. They all have the same end result.

Comment: Does the properties actual name class as the key because i am not giving them any keys when i add the data to the array

Comment: Yes, the key is used to search for an accessor method to call